# Angular Reactive Form - Validation is not working in formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups, angular-validation

I have this form group defined

```js
get createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        mobile: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

Generating fields like this

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


    <div class="row" formArrayName="address" *ngFor="let fields of AddressInfo.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <div class="each_content">
                    <label class="labelTitle">Name <span class="validation-error">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control height-reset" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" formControlName="name" />

                    <div
                            *ngIf="dynamicFormGroup.get('name').invalid && (dynamicFormGroup.get('name').dirty || dynamicFormGroup.get('name').touched)">
                        <small class="validation-error">Please provide a title.</small>
                    </div>
```

However, the validation is not working, any solution thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information and code on how you are initializing your formGroup. Where and how is the createItem method used?

Comment: @JB17 https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fehgv6?file=src%2Fmain.html pls check this link

Comment: The StackBlitz link you shared is not same as your question.

Comment: @YongShun yes but when i add validator then validation error message is not displayed

Comment: @YongShun i tried adding this code  `<div
                *ngIf="dynamicFormGroup.get('name').invalid && (dynamicFormGroup.get('name').dirty || dynamicFormGroup.get('name').touched)">
                <small class="validation-error">Please provide a title.</small>
                </div>`

Comment: Try to provide the full structure of your Reactive Form or edit the StackBlitz to reproduce the error. Does your `name` form control really exist in the form group under `address` form array?

Comment: @YongShun yes  name and other formControl exists

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the error is not shown as it must fulfill these conditions:

- The control's value is invalid.
- The control is either `dirty` or `touched` state.

When you submit the form without touching/inputting the form control(s) which has the validation, the second condition will not be fulfilled.

Hence, when you submit the form, you need to set the form control(s) as `dirty` or `touched` state. You can use the `markAllAsTouched` method from the root `FormGroup` to mark all the controls as touched.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.dynamicFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();

  ...
}
```

Back to the part discussed in the comment, the `name` control doesn't exist in the FormGroup of `address` `FormArray`. So unsure why you place the validation error message template under there.

I demonstrate one of the controls that fall under the `address` FormArray: "streetAddress". To retrieve the `streetAddress` control, you need to provide the index of `address` `FormArray` as below:

```
addressFormGroup(i: number) {
  return this.AddressInfo.controls[`${i}`] as FormGroup;
}
```

```
<div
  *ngIf="addressFormGroup(i).get('streetAddress')?.invalid && (addressFormGroup(i).get('streetAddress')?.dirty || addressFormGroup(i).get('streetAddress')?.touched)"
>
  <small class="validation-error"
    >Please provide a Street Address.</small
  >
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vfkp5b?file=src%2Fmain.html)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kba6x9?file=src%2Fmain.html&file=src%2Fmain.ts) a bit and made some minor changes. Please check and see if it works for you.
I introduced a `hasError` function, which takes the according input and checks the validity.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamicFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      address: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()]),
    });
  }

  get addresses(): FormArray {
    return this.dynamicFormGroup.get('address') as FormArray;
  }

  hasError(index: number, controlName: string): boolean {
    const control = this.addresses.at(index).get(controlName);
    if (control) {
      return control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched);
    }
    return false;
  }

  addNewAddress(): void {
    this.addresses.push(this.createItem());
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      streetAddress: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

The template would look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-row" formArrayName="address">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let adress of addresses.controls; index as i">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="password"><b>Street Address</b></label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Street Address"
              name="SA"
              formControlName="streetAddress"
            />
            <div *ngIf="hasError(i, 'streetAddress')">
              <small class="validation-error">Please provide a title.</small>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Other input fields -->

        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

The `dynamicFormGroup.get('name').invalid` in your code would not return anything, since you are trying to get a formGroup inside of the form, but you would need a specific formGroup inside of the nested formArray.

*dynamicFormGroup --> adresses --> specific name input*

By passing the index and the formControlName to the hasError function this should work.

Comment: Thanks but when i run it does not show error message

Comment: I only added the error message to the street-adress. Enter a value and then delete it again. The required validator will fire and show the message beneath the according input.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I forgot indicate in .css is ìnput.ng-invalid.ng-touched. If you not indicate "input" not work

You can use

```
dynamicFormGroup.get('address.'+i+'.name')
```

or

```
AddressInfo.at(i).get('name')
```

To "reach" the formControl inside the FormArray, but I suggest another approach

As Angular mark an invalid FormControl with the class ng-invalid ng-touched and ng-dirty in a formCotnrol and ng-submit in a form. you can take advantage of it using the [subsequent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator) `~`

If you use some like

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
  <div formArrayName="address">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let fields of AddressInfo.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <div class="each_content">
              <input type="text" class="form-control height-reset" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" formControlName="name" />
              <label class="labelTitle">Name <span class="validation-error">*</span></label>

              <div ><small class="validation-error">Please provide a title.</small></div>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

NOTE: I like more use the loop in a ng-container inside a div FormArray

Where

```
onSubmit(){
   if (!this.dynamicFromGroup.valid)
      this.dynamicFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
   else
   {
      ...do something...
   }
}
```

You can use a .css like

```
.labelTitle{
  float:left;
}
.validation-error
{
   display:none; //<--see that by defect display is none
   color:red;
}
.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~ div .validation-error
{
   display:inline-block; //<---but where have a "brother" invalid
}
.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~ label 
{
   height:1.5rem;
}
.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~ label .validation-error
{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Really it's a bit complex -I need use label `float:left` because the "*"

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vdkszz?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)